# import file by url route python

Tags: python, url, import, flask

Im trying to import files on Flask app in base of url route. I started to coding python few days ago so i havent idea if i doing it well. I write this on :

```
@app.route('/<file>')
def call(file):
    __import__('controller.'+file)
    hello = Example('Hello world')
    return hello.msg
```

And i have other file called `example.py` into a controller folder that contains this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
```

So i start from terminal the app and i try to enter to `localhost:5000/example`.
Im trying to show in screen `Hello world` but give me the next error:

```
NameError: global name 'Example' is not defined
```

Thanks for all!

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to use `__import__(<module>)` instead of `import module`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__import__` returns the newly imported module; names from that module are *not* added to your globals, so you need to get the `Example` class as an attribute from the returned module:

```
module = __import__('controller.'+file)
hello = module.Example('Hello world')
```

`__import__` is rather low-level, you probably want to use [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) instead:

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('controller.'+file)
hello = module.Example('Hello world')
```

If you need to dynamically get the classname too, use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
class_name = 'Example'
hello_class = getattr(module, class_name)
hello = hello_class('Hello world')
```

The Werkzeug package (used by Flask) offers a helpful functions here: [`werkzeug.utils.import_string()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/utils/#werkzeug.utils.import_string) imports an *object* dynamically:

```
from werkzeug.utils import import_string

object_name = 'controller.{}:Example'.format(file)
hello_class = import_string(object_name)
```

This encapsulates the above process.

You'll need to be **extremely careful** with accepting names from web requests and using those as module names. Please do sanitise the `file` argument and only allow alphanumerics to prevent relative imports from being used.

You could use the [`werkzeug.utils.find_modules()` function](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/utils/#werkzeug.utils.find_modules) to limit the possible values for `file` here:

```
from werkzeug.utils import find_modules, import_string

module_name = 'controller.{}'.format(file)
if module_name not in set(find_modules('controller')):
    abort(404)  # no such module in the controller package

hello_class = import_string(module_name + ':Example')
```

Comment: Huh, didn't know about importlib - I just learned something new :)

Comment: This is exactly that i want. Thanks!

Comment: I have to agree with @Martijn Pieters here - this sounds like something risky to do in a web app. Are you certain this is required in your case?

Comment: @LukasKas: I recalled Werkzeug had some utility functions that help here; added.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not add the directory to the file, add the following code into the previous python program

```
# Add another directory
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/your_directory')

from Example import Example
```

Comment: yeah, but im trying to do it dynamically, without knows class or file name

Comment: try import os and get all subdirectories by `os.listdir('./')`, make an iteration to import all subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for you to do imports in Python:

```
import example

e = example.Example('hello world')
```

or

```
from example import Example

e = Example('hello world')
```

Comment: Sure, but the OP is trying to use a *dynamic* import.

Comment: Maybe, but he did not write that and he also stated he just started with python a couple of days ago. I prefer to assume the basics to begin with

Comment: From the [comment an another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136729/import-file-by-url-route-python/27136850?noredirect=1#comment42771893_27136820): *yeah, but im trying to do it dynamically, without knows class or file name*

Comment: Yeas, you are right - but i did not have that information when i wrote my answer :p

Comment: Well, the use of `__import__()` with a variable taken from the URL was a big hint too.